# What should the ratio/relationship between parameterServerType and workerCount be?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to use Tensorflow Object Detection API to train a MobileNet V1 SSD on Cloud ML Engine and I would like to speed up my training time. Common sense says that one should ideally increase the `workerCount` but that seems to be experimental. Some posts talk about properly setting the values for `parameterServerCount` and `workerCount` but I cannot find any good documentation relating to the same. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: If the MobileNet V1 SSD does not provide guidance, then you will likely have to guess and check. I'm not familiar enough with that exact model to provide good guidance. If your training program supports using multiple GPUs, your best bet is to get as many GPUs as you can afford on a single machine and then you don't have to worry about workers and parameter servers and are likely to get very good performance.

Answer (score 0):

These fields are for distributed training: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed

More workers will speed up training speed in general but the speedup could become marginal at certain point.

parameterServerType is used to store model parameters, and as long as it's not the bottleneck, you don't need to add more.